# How to show like an circular Image view moving from collpasing bar to toolbar while collapsing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have one toolbar and one circular image view inside collapsing bar. if i collapsed the toolbar i have show the shrink the imageview and moved towards toolbar. how to achieve this translation.

Comment: I found related article here http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/android-tip-custom-coordinatorlayout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not so hard check this out

[Mastering the Coordinator Layout](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)

Comment: Thank for sharing this and i found related article here also  http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/android-tip-custom-coordinatorlayout.html

Comment: you're welcome. if it helps you up vote and accept answer ;) @VigneshKumar